# How to dynamically pickup new smart contract compiled ABI without restarting the nodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, quorum

Use case is: My nodeJS server is up and running and i have changed the smart contract, and compiled. Now I have the new ABI. I have written an API where i can upgrade the smart contract.

My question is: If I don't restart the nodeJS server, will it pick up the new smart contract compiled ABI. If yes, then can anyone please explain how it works.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge on the subject goes, the ABI is the interface you use to communicate with the smart-contract that is located on the blockchain.

This means that when you make changes to the contract you will need to re-deploy it, or your application no longer knows how to communicate with the contract.

Beside that contracts are not meant to be changed, once deployed only the state of the data contained in the contract should be modified.

See this link for more information on the last statement:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11938/how-to-update-a-deployed-smart-contract